# How to display data in table format in Vue Atlas

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-atlas

I need to display user data in table format with a approval button in every row. That approval button should call function for row update. My code doesn't work as intended and I don't know why.

My code:

```html
             <template>
            <div>
              <va-card  >
                <h3>Users waiting for Approval </h3>
              </va-card>
            </div>  
            </template>

            <script>
            import axios from 'axios';

            export default{
                data: function{
                    return{
                        userData:'',
                    }
                },
                mounted(){
                    var self = this;

                    axios.get('') //api call
                    .then(function(res){
                        self.userData = res.data;

                              console.log("userdata",self.userdata)
                    }
                }
             }
```

Api data output:

```
        [
          {
            "email": "asa", 
            "phone": "121212121", 
            "time": "2019-09-03T09:52:04.062486302Z", 
            "username": "as"
          }, 
          {
            "email": "asa@adsa", 
            "phone": "1231231312", 
            "time": "2019-09-03T09:52:22.296617365Z", 
            "username": "asa"
          }, 
          {
            "email": "test@gmail.com", 
            "phone": "1342132141414", 
            "time": "2019-09-03T09:52:47.201341563Z", 
            "username": "test"
          }
        ]
```

Comment: There are loads of table components for vue literally a whole webpage here https://vuejsexamples.com/tag/table/ with examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using vue-atlas library you could do it like :

```
<va-table :hover="hover" :size="size" v-if="userData.length">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>email</th>
        <th>phone</th>
        <th>time</th>
        <th>username</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    </tbody>
    <tr v-for="user in userData">
        <td v-for="v in user">{{v}}</td>
        <td><va-button type="danger"><va-icon type="trash" /></va-button></td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</va-table>
```

your data object :

```
 data () {
    return {
      hover: true,
      size: 'lg',
      userData :[]
    }
  }
```

Comment: thank you bro... and one more i need a button for approval should call an API for update that row

Comment: i don't understand what do you mean by that button

Comment: in every end of row a button . for example delete that user

Comment: try `v-if="userData && userData.length"`

Comment: <td><va-button   v-on:click="approve(this.user.username)"> Approve</va-button></td>    bro how can i pass that username after clicking that button to approve function

Comment: you should pass only `user.name` like `v-on:click="approve(user.username)"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198889/discussion-between-pavan-and-boussadjra-brahim).